# Banno EES Event 110010 "Device Registered" not returning an IP

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit, jackhenry-jxchange

On jackhenry.dev it has the Banno EES Event 110010 listed as supporting "[Device Registered](https://jackhenry.dev/open-enterprise-api-docs/enterprise-event-system/event-publishers/banno/110010-banno-event/developer-resource/)" that happens when a user logs in from a new device. It has a change.affectedPerson.personip listed.

However, personip is returning blank.  It also seems to be triggering even when a new device is not registered.  How do we get the IP when a new device is registered?

I setup an EES event:

```
Event Number: 110010
Rules: name = DeviceRegistered
```

And was expecting it to return like on the documentation page when a new device is registered:

```
{
 "eventId": "a9eef6eb-f717-414c-9145-eb894ac1d00d",
 "date": "1979-09-30T21:08:48.426Z",
 "institutionId": "edf692e7-fe0b-40de-ba39-e040cc318b4c",
 "change": {
 "application": "devices",
 "name": "DeviceRegistered",
 "affectedPerson": {
 "personId": "b6e1b00c-b86d-4630-a06e-456a3cae7ec1",
 "fullName": "Benjamin Garcia",
 "personIp": "116.123.1.255"
 },
 "deviceId": "1852a68b-1815-4150-917f-80d0d43ccdf7"
 }
}
```

But it seems to launch anytime anyone logs in and personIp is null.

Comment: We're checking with Engineering on this one, and why the `personIp` is null. Separately, you mentioned "it seems to launch anytime anyone logs in"...can you elaborate on when you do and when you do not see the event itself being emitted?

Comment: Thank you.  It seems to trigger on all logins not just logins on new devices.  Like if I close and re-open the app.  It could possibly be other things triggering it too.  When we turn it on for name=RegisteredDevice it's triggering at about the same rate as logins.